# Creating a new column based on the mean of other values in group(with infinite sum)

Tags: python, pandas, math, lambda, sum

A few days ago, I asked this question [Creating a new column based on the mean of other values in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060837/creating-a-new-column-based-on-the-mean-of-other-values-in-group)

The answer was great. However, the issue is we have so many 0.000001 values etc. and these converge to inf or -inf values. The data is financial data and these little numbers mean a lot to us.
So, instead of converging to infinity, I still want to take sum and calculate the mean.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382411/how-to-perform-infinite-sum-numerically-in-python) such that, using nsum module in the math package, is doable. however, the transform function does not have any properties to work with nsum. As a side note, if anyone wants to refresh the memory, [here is some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922511/replace-all-inf-inf-values-with-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe) on how -inf  vs inf values occur:

SO the question is, how to take the sum of infinite values with a transform? or how to change the below code?

A small mock data:

```
d = {'col1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "c", "c","c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e"], 
     'col2': [2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2015, 2016, 2017], 
     'col3': [1E307, -1E305, -1E30700080, -3E30700080, 0.3E30700080, 0.00005, -0.005291, 8, -9, 10, 50, 60, -70, 40, 60]],
     'group':[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,20]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The solution with sum:

```
df['means'] = df.groupby("group").apply(lambda x: x.groupby("col2")["col3"].transform("sum").sub(x["col3"]).div(len(x["col1"].unique())-1)).droplevel(0)
```

Comment: have you checked numpy.longfloat or mpmath ?

Comment: no. I just searched for it, couldnot find any results either. any suggestion?

Comment: quite explanatory answer is here, but you can simply test by applying the dtype to the columns needed.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25481654/8805842
 https://mpmath.org/ is here...
P.S. I am not experienced in these fields, just saw these before and recalled

Comment: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'loungdouble' ... no idea what's going on with this....

Comment: Sorry, can you please check it now?

Comment: "loungdouble" is misspelled